# Extract content from div elements

Tags: javascript, html, csv, dom

I have an HTML file with many div elements like this

```
<div data-store="&#123;&quot;timestamp&quot;:8479216890119,&quot;author&quot;:8819156222,&quot;uuid&quot;:&quot;mid.8473116890448:a31179k549&quot;&#125;" data-sigil="message-text">
    <span>A message</span>
</div>
```

I want to convert it to a CSV file with content

```
timestamp,author,text
8479216890119,8819156222,A message
...
```

So the HTML file contains many different div elements, but I am only interested in those div elements with the attribute `data-store`. And from this div element, I want to extract `timestamp` and `author` from the `data-store` attribute and the text from the span element inside the div element.

I know I can do this with some regular expression, but I wonder if it might be easier to do something like

```
let csv = 'timestamp,author,text\n';
document.querySelector('div').forEach((el) => {
  const data = el.getAttribute('data-store');
  if (data) {
    const timestamp = ?; // extract from data
    const author = ?; // extract from data
    const text = el.childElement('span').innerHTML();
    csv += timestamp + ',' + author + ',' + text + '\n';
  }
});

document.write(csv);
```

I know that this code won't work, but I guess it might be possible to do something like this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Is the content of `data-store` always in (HTML entity encoded) JSON format?

Comment: It is always like presented in the question. I don't think it looks like JSON format, but I am not sure?

Comment: @Jamgreen As in answer below, it's a json object *encoded*, so with special chars converted. You can parse it with javascript as normal json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code should be parse by javascript itself, converting the special chars.   And it's a json object, so you can decode it and retrieve what you want.

Note that for a rappresentation as wanted by you, i used both `\n` and `<br>`.   Since you're printing on the document, should be sufficient the `<br>`.

**edit**

I forgot to point out that you can directly retrive all div with *data-store* attribute.

A shrewdness you should considerate is check if the json property exist before using. i.e `let time_stamp = (data.timestamp!=undefined) ? data.timestamp : null;

```js
let csv = 'timestamp,author,text\n<br>';

$('div[data-store]').each(function() {
  let data = $.parseJSON($(this).attr('data-store'));
  csv += data.timestamp + ',' + data.author + ',' + $(this).find('span').html() + '\n<br>';
});

document.write(csv);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-store="&#123;&quot;timestamp&quot;:8479216890119,&quot;author&quot;:8819156222,&quot;uuid&quot;:&quot;mid.8473116890448:a31179k549&quot;&#125;" data-sigil="message-text">
  <span>A message</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample example to save div with attribute 'data-store' information as csv:

```js
var csv = 'timestamp,author,text\n<br>';
$('.main div[data-store]').each(function(index,el){
  var req_data = $.parseJSON($(this).attr('data-store'));
  var timestamp = req_data.timestamp;
  var author = req_data.author;
  var msg = $.trim($(this).find('span').text());
  csv+=timestamp+","+author+","+msg+"\n<br>";
});
document.write(csv);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main'>
<div data-store="&#123;&quot;timestamp&quot;:8479216890119,&quot;author&quot;:8819156222,&quot;uuid&quot;:&quot;mid.8473116890448:a31179k549&quot;&#125;" data-sigil="message-text">
    <span>A message1</span>
</div>
<div data-store="&#123;&quot;timestamp&quot;:8479216890119,&quot;author&quot;:8819156222,&quot;uuid&quot;:&quot;mid.8473116890448:a31179k549&quot;&#125;" data-sigil="message-text">
    <span>A message2</span>
</div>
<div data-sigil="message-text">
    <span>A message3</span>
</div>
</div>
```